# Determine Linux Version

Tags: linux, rhel, version

How do I determine the RHEL version by looking at this extraction, I can only know that it is RHEL7 from el7 but what is the exact version?

```
Command: /bin/uname -a
====================================================
Linux xxxxxxxxx 3.10.0-957.12.2.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Apr 19 21:09:07 
UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Try `$ sudo lsb_release -a`

Answer (score 1):

In the Fedora/RHEL/CentOS family, you can use:

```
cat /etc/*-release
```

That will give you the exact version.

As root, you can also install `redhat-lsb-core` and use:

```
lsb_release -a
```